# Joomla 3.4 Multi-language site functionality

Tags: multilingual, google-translate, joomla3.4

I am developing an accommodation booking website on Joomla 3.4.3 and i have installed Falang. My website must have two languages, default is English(en-GB) and translated to Afrikaans(af-ZA).

Before i go further into translating content for Falang, i want to find out what the 'Best Practice' for creating a Multi-lingual website **currently** is. I know that Falang is a great option(free or premium), but does Joomla 3.4.3 have the same capability?

I read that in order to offer multi-language with the built-in language switching functionality of Joomla, one would need to duplicate ALL content(Menus, Articles, etc.) and translate to the respective languages. After following multiple tutorials which may have been outdated, i got the built-in functionality to (sort of) work.

With Falang, it is basically the same process, just made a bit easier by allowing the user to do all translations in one area(Components-> Falang-> Translation-> And select the required content and language.)

**Questions:**

1- Is my above statement true in terms of Joomla and Falang multi-language functionality?

2- Has **Joomla 3.4** made it easier to create multi-language websites without having to use 3rd party software? i.e.: Is there a new, easy way to work with Joomla multi-language? Or is it still the same old procedure?

3- Would it be safe to say that using Falang would still be the best option? (between Joomla 3.4 language switching and Falang)

4- Does anyone know of a Joomla Extension that can **automatically translate** newly added content without Admin having to translate the information?

5- Would Google Translate be an option to use **instead of** Falang?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No, Falang, does not user the built in system for Joomla. It stores translations in it's own database.
2. It is still the same procedure. It is complicated, but it works well if you have no 3rd party extensions.
3. No, I would greatly recommend our solution [Neno Translate](https://www.neno-translate.com) it allows you to translate ANY 3rd party extension and does not slow down your site. It is also a lot easier to find and manage your translatable content and allows you to order professional or machine translation of all your content with the click of a button
4. Yes, Neno Translate.
5. If you mean GTranslate, then I would say no, as it does not allow you to configure what is translated or edit the translations afterwards.